# Yii2 module url modification

Tags: php, yii2

In my app I have a module located in:

> /frontend/modules/reports/controllers/TheModule.php/
>
> frontend/modules/reports/controllers/views/the-module/index.php

The url for this is

> frontend/web/reports/the-module/index

How can I have the url like this:

> frontend/web/the-module/index ?

Because if I navigate to the module url as it is now, all the links in the main menu (which is common throughout the site) will get a /reports in their url.

Note that I am using the default url manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in frontend configuration:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        // ...
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'the-module/<action>' => 'reports/the-module/<action>'
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: Thank you Bizley, I can now call the module as frontend/web/fr-cashing-and-payment/index , which is prefect, but the main menu still has that "/reports/" inserted in all the urls.

Comment: <?= Url::to(['controller/action']) ?> , for example : <?= Url::to(['user/profile']) ?>

Comment: When you are inside the module all routes are relative, so you have to use <?= Url::to(['/user/profile']) ?> (with `/` at the beginning)

Comment: I've modified one of the items in the menu and added the / in front, it works. But there is a big problem: all the URLs are written like that and I would prefer not to change everywhere in the code, due to a number of reasons. How can I do this change without modifying all the URLs everywhere, and also without modifying in the core of Yii ?

Comment: I guess you can use UrlNormalizer for that http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlnormalizer.html